# OutOfMemory Bitmap issue

Tags: java, android, performance, android-bitmap, kotlin-android-extensions

I am making a memo type application. When a user wants to create a memo he/she can add multiple images to that memo. Everything works fine but when I add multiple memos with images my application crashes with a java.lang.OutOfMemory Exception. I know this is related to Bitmaps so this is a sample code:

```
noteImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(originalExtImgPath)
```

And after that I save these Bitmaps on internal memory

```
`AsyncTask.execute {
        for (index in images.indices) {
            storage.createFile("Images", paths[index], images[index])
        }
    }`
```

I have added only three images and this is how much memory it is using.

[image]

How can I manage this so that it uses less memory? Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html

Comment: Take heap dumps and figure out where you're using memory (and most likely leaking it).  Memory issues are never about implementing one trick, its about understanding where memory is used as a whole and addressing the entire app.  For bitmaps, don't load them into memory until necessary, release them when possible, and use a cache.

Comment: @GabeSechan what do you mean by release Bitmaps when possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically speaking, The problem is that you're trying to load a big image into the memory. There is not enough memory to store all the images and your app crashes.
The trick is to reduce the memory footprint of the bitmap.

There is a great article about this on the Android developers site:
[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)